# QGIS: Importing geotagged photos 'Could not open' error

Tags: qgis, photos, geotag, iphone

I am having a hard time importing geotagged photos using the 'Import geotagged photos' tool within QGIS 3.10. The photos I am importing do have GPS information within their properties, so I can't put my finger on why they are not being uploaded. This tool seems to work just fine when importing sample photos provided by my professor, but not with photos taken with my own iPhone. This message (in red) is popping up:
[image: error message]

Can anybody help me?

In reply to HeikkiVesanto's comment - To transfer the photos from my phone to my laptop I first uploaded them to OneDrive then downloaded them from my laptop. Perhaps this is why they are in JPG. Also, the 'Import geotagged photos' tool requires photos to be in jpeg format so I don't think the image format is the issues. Also, yes my location was on. In fact, when I enter the photo's properties on my computer the longitude, latitude and altitude are all visible.

In reply to @GabrielC’s suggestion, I had tried placing the folder in my desktop and importing the photos from that location, to no avail.

Comment: You really need to make your folders shorter, get rid of the spaces, for example replacing them by _ underscores. Too long file paths always causes problems. Try putting your images in a test folder near the root of the drive and see what it does.

Comment: Is that really how the iPhone is storing the raw photos in jpg? That's a really lossy format. I would have expected .png. Also did you turn on location on the camera when you took the photos?

Comment: In reply to HeikkiVesanto's comment - To transfer the photos from my phone to my laptop I first uploaded them to OneDrive then downloaded them from my laptop. Perhaps this is why they are in JPG? Also, the 'Import geotagged photos' tool requires photos to be in jpeg format so I don't think the image format is the issues. Also, yes my location was on. In fact, when I enter the photo's properties on my computer the longitude, latitude and altitude are all visible

Comment: Gabriel C. - Thanks for your suggestion. I had tried placing the folder on my desktop and importing the photos from that location, to no avail.

Comment: @Kristina Even if it doesn't solve your problem, if you are going to work with GIS software on the long term (if not don't worry too much about it), simple file paths is more of a requirement than a suggestion. There are many tools based on different code libraries that all have specific quirky ways of dealing with file paths. To reduce future headaches, the two rules I mentioned earlier cover almost all path problems.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as @Kristina - with certain photos and not others.  Path length does not seem to matter.  For instance I get this error `Could not open E:\_TEMP\test\DSC_3793.JPG` - but if I drag/drop the image onto Google Earth, it is recognized as geotagged. I'm using QGIS version 3.22.3

Answer (score 2):

Note that the recent versions of iOS, do not include exif information when for example  download the images from web. The only method is to use itune software and there is an option to attach exif information.

To ensure you have the exif data, could you use a exif tool from command line or an online tool (e.g. https://www.pic2map.com/) and see if the exif data have been transferred correctly.

On another note, you can use https://inputapp.io (see disclaimer) to take geotagged photo. Input is an app based on QGIS and works on iOS and Android. For more information on how to set up a project in QGIS and use it in Input app, you can read the step-by-step guide here:
https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2021/04/20/photo-exif-input/

**Disclaimer** we are developers of the Input app.

Comment: The exif data should be there because I tried uploading a photo in the website you included in your answer and the location came up quite accurately.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using QGIS on Windows.

There were issues with `Import geotagged photos` on Windows related to OSGeo4W:

- https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/654
- https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/3284
- https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/40583

Since you're using QGIS 3.10, I think your import problems would be resolved using a more up-to-date release, e.g. 3.18.2 or ​3.16.6 LTR.

Comment: My import problem was not solved by using QGIS 3.22.3, nor by shortening the paths.